# Adding multiple tables in Email using mailR (send.mail)

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes say df1, df2, df3 and I want to send it in an email as 3 separate tables with some space between them.

I am able to currently send 1 dataframe as table with below code

```
library("mailR")


df1 <- read.csv('Adhoc/temp.csv')

final1 <- print(xtable(df1,caption = "Report"), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE,
            caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"),
            html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes","border=1"))


date_of_report<- Sys.Date() - 1

    send.mail(from = "no-reply@abc.com",
              to = c('xyz.pqr@abc.com'
              ),
              subject = paste('Report', date_of_report, sep=' '),
              body = final1,
              html = TRUE,
              smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
              authenticate = FALSE,
              send = TRUE,
              debug=TRUE)
```

I wanted some help so that I can send all the dataframes in one email itself. Currently I send 3 such emails.

Comment: Can't you just add another `xtable` expression using `paste` in the definition of `final1`? If neccessary add some linebreaks? I've never used that package but it looks like if whatever you print there ends up in the message body. Is there a reason why you would use `print` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested **untested** Solution: `paste` multiple pre-formatted tables:

```
final1 <- print(xtable(df1,caption = "Report"), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE,
        caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"),
        html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes","border=1"))

final2 <- print(xtable(df2,caption = "Report2"), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE,
        caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"),
        html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes","border=1"))

final3 <- print(xtable(df3,caption = "Report3"), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE,
        caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"),
        html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes","border=1"))


final <- paste(final1, final2, final3, sep="\n")

date_of_report<- Sys.Date() - 1

send.mail(from = "no-reply@abc.com",
          to = c('xyz.pqr@abc.com'
          ),
          subject = paste('Report', date_of_report, sep=' '),
          body = final,
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
          authenticate = FALSE,
          send = TRUE,
          debug=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes a lot of sense to define a function, here. And then there are a couple of things I would change up for future extensibility.

```
library(xtable) # This is required for the xtable function and print method
library(mailR)

# Read the data.frames into a list. This makes it easier to add/remove tables later
dfs <- list(
  `Report 1` = data.frame(letter = LETTERS[seq_len(5L)],
                          number = seq_len(5L),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                          ),
  `Report 2` = data.frame(letter = letters[6L + seq_len(5L)],
                          number = 6L + seq_len(5L),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                          ),
  `Report 3` = data.frame(letter = LETTERS[20L:16L],
                          number = 20L:16L,
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )
```

Now we need to define the function that will format one of our tables. I'm just calling it `make_xtable`, and I'm giving it two arguments, the first is a data.frame, and the second is a string that will be used as the caption.

```
make_xtable <- function(df, caption) {
  print(
    xtable(df, caption = caption), 
    type = "html", 
    include.rownames = FALSE,
    caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"),
    html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes", "border=1"),
    print.results = FALSE # This suppresses the results from printing to the console
    )
}
```

So far we've loaded in our data, and we've defined a process for creating the tables from a given data.frame and caption string, but we still need to actually run each of our tables through the process. Here is where putting our data.frames into a list will come in handy. The family of `apply` functions will help us run the function on every element of our list, and then `paste0` will let us combine the resulting character vector into a character object of length 1.

```
email_body <-
  paste0(
    mapply(
      make_xtable,
      dfs, # The list of data.frames containing our data
      names(dfs) # Names attribute of the list of data.frames
      ),
    collapse = "<br \>" # Concatenate using an HTML newline as a separator
    )
```

Then use `email_body` as the argument `body` in the `send.mail` function.